# Invalid grant in OAuth2 in GAE java appp

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0

Hi i am trying to create a GAE/J app in which i have to retrieve access token from a given code

so here is my code for /oauth2callback servlet

```
public class OAuth2Callback extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
    String url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

        // FetchOptions opt = FetchOptions.Builder.doNotValidateCertificate();
           URL url1=new URL(url); 
           String param="grant_type=authorization_code&code="+req.getParameter("code")+"&client_id=anonymouns&client_secret=anonymous&redirect_uri=https://www.cloudspokestest.appspot.com/oauth2callback";

   HttpURLConnection connection = 
        (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection(); 
             connection.setDoOutput(true); 
             connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
             connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
             connection.getOutputStream().write( param.getBytes() ); 
          InputStream str= connection.getInputStream();
          BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(str));
        String l="";
          while((l=reader.readLine())!=null){
              resp.getWriter().println(l);

          }


    }

}
```

but on the browser screen i am getting error invalid grant with response code 400.can any one please help how to remove this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error most likely because the parameter values in your url are not url-encoded. The value of the `redirect_uri`, and possibly the value of `code` must be url-encoded.

You could use java.net.URLEncoder to encode the values.

Also never use `getBytes()` on a String, as it uses your platform's default character encoding to convert characters to bytes. Running the same code on another machine, or changing your machines configuration might give different output. Always use `getBytes(charsetname)` instead.

Comment: BTW, the same goes for `new InputStreamReader(str)`. This will also use your default encoding to convert bytes to characters. Use `new InputStreamReader(str, charsetname)` instead.